# How to run sql script through powershell (Scripts/Commands)

Tags: sql-server, powershell, scripting

I am trying to run an sql script by writing powershell script(commands). I am using below Invoke-Command for running the sql script.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {D:\000000000041906_JCWJOUYKDB\dm_sql1.sql}
```

But the script is not executing, but if I am running a bat script it is running perfectly.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {D:\000000000041906_JCWJOUYKDB\dm_os1.bat}
```

The bat script are just making directories by connecting to remote machine, where as in sql scripts I have define connecting string for sql server and from there create tablespaces.

Comment: So what do you think is going to run the .sql script at the other end of the session? How is it going to know what database server to connect to, with which credentials, and which database to invoke the commands in? You probably want to use [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd) over the session to execute the script, supplying the appropriate parameters.

Comment: Inside sql script I have given sql connection string like sqlplus user/pass@instance